# AWS s3 cp command returns: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the ListObjects operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I've got a user with permission with the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy, my bucketname is `abcxyzchristest`.

I've configured the AWS cli with the above user.

When running `aws s3 cp --region eu s3://abcxyzchristest/ abcxyz` I get:

```
fatal error: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the ListObjects operation: Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256
```

What is the cause of the error?

Comment: Possibly that `eu` is not a region? It should be something like `eu-west-1`, for example. Can you insert your full region to that and try again?

Comment: How can I determine which region my bucket is in? It just says 'EU (Frankfurt)' in the s3 console

Comment: Check here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region  Frankfurt is `eu-central-1`

Comment: `aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket BUCKET`

Thank you that solved my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due the incorrect region specified.

I had to do:
`aws s3 cp --region eu-central-1 s3://abcxyzchristest/ bobby`

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps to solve this problem:

1) Configure your command line aws

```
[root@ip-172-31-18-132 ec2-user]# aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]:
AWS Secret Access Key [None]:
Default region name [ap-south-1a]: ap-south-1 <-- give your region here
Default output format [None]:
```

2) Specify your region in the s3 cp command

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://buckername /home/ec2-user --region ap-south-1
```